# Do async function keep running when route change in Vuejs?

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

I'm new to vuejs,
I'm trying to do some data downloading from inside Vue View, using function inside methods, I wonder if I leave that view(change route), is the downloading process still running? (in this case I'm downloading from firestore, some huge databases)

Any advice on how it should be done? So that the database download keep running regardless of route change?

Any help is much  appreciated

Edit:
To clarify, my case are like this :

1. User open some page
2. The page download some data in background(will take some time)
3. User move to another page

What I'm asking are how did I make the data download process continue running, even though user move to another route?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, I finally put the function inside vuex action, and call it using this.$store.dispatch(function name). It work flawlessly. even though I keep changing route/view, the bg process(action) keep running.

notes: I don't need the downloaded data to be binded/reactive, I just need to download the data in background and save it to localforage

Answer (score 3):

If you are developing an SPA with Vue Router, the [`keep-alive`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-dynamic-async.html) element might help you in this issue.

Basically, according to the [Vue JS Lifecycle Diagram](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/instance.html#Lifecycle-Diagram), once a component is destroyed, all directives of the Vue instance have been unbound, all event listeners have been removed, and all child Vue instances have also been destroyed.

Comment: Thanks for responding, I'm sorry I just edited my questions with my case detail, so will keep-alive work in my case? Are there nothing in Vue that work in background regardless the route?

Comment: Are you using Vue Router `router-view`?

Comment: Yes,, I'm using Vue router

Comment: Then yes, `keep-alive` will help you in your case. That will cache the state, reading progress, etc. of a `router-view` so you don't have to download that page every time.

Comment: Again, thanks for the suggestions, but if I don't want to use keep-alive, can I write the download function in vuex action, and call it from component? Will it became background process? (when I move to other route, the vuex action will still running

Comment: You can try [Vuex Data Pre-Fetching](https://ssr.vuejs.org/guide/data.html#data-store), Check it out if this will somehow help you with your case.